# Is it possible to create pipeline sharing all variables but some stages could be manualy ran?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to create Jenkins pipeline of few stages. Specificaly pipeline for uploading.
Examples:

Set version to upload -> set other variables -> upload artifacts A -> upload artifacts B -> artifacts C -> correct?

This is ok, but what if I want to upload only B? Do I have to create input "Do you want to upload A/B/C?" and then solve it with if blocks?

Is there better way?
I used to use Task plugin for this, but the problem is that it is too static and also it doesn't share variables between tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins Pipeline, whether intentionally or unintentionally, doesn't seem to be supportive of "skipping stages". I understand why they would do this - is a pipeline valid if an app takes a different path each time? Not sure.

We have several cases where we do exactly what you describe: pose an input question about what actions to perform, and then have if/else conditionals that perform those actions all within a single stage. We use it typically for "Which DEV environments do you want to deploy to? DEV1, DEV2, etc." since different developers want to use one of multiple dev environments. Our higher environments and deeper testing do not allow these conditionals.